# Where's the path?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

A person was shading several unit squares in a square grid, to create a path from the bottom left corner to the top right corner. The path stepped from each square to the next either horizontally or vertically to create the path, but not diagonally.

For each row and column in that grid, the person wrote the number of shaded squares it contained on the edge of the grid. Here is an example:

[image: example]

Then, he drew another path but it but some parts were erased out. Here is the remainder of his path:

[image: puzzle]

Your job is to find out the remainder of the path with an explanation.

Comment: Did you create this yourself?

Comment: A friend gave it to me

Comment: This type of puzzle is commonly called "Tracks", with the path being displayed as railroad tracks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

Progress:

> [image]
>  (The key breakthroughs are the rows with number 1.)

Comment: How did you eliminate other possible path with 1s (top one on the right, bottom on the left)? Because top rows are both 5, making this obviously impossible?

Comment: @ZizyArcher Yeah that's right. That's exactly what I thought.